# Prevent to Be Crawled by a Script

Tags: php, apache, curl

I was trying to read a page from the same site using PHP. I came across this [good discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3620702/583539) and decided to use the *cURL* method suggested:

```
function get_web_page( $url )
{
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}

//Now get the webpage
$data = get_web_page( "https://www.google.com/" );

//Display the data (optional)
echo "<pre>" . $data['content'] . "</pre>";
```

So, for my case, I called the `get_web_page` like this:

```
$target_url = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/press-release/index.html";           
$page = get_web_page($target_url);
```

The thing that I couldn't fathom is it worked on all of my test servers but one. I've verified that the *cURL* is available on the server in question. Also, setting `$target_url = "http://www.google.com" worked fine. So, I am pretty positive that the culprit has nothing to do with the *cURL* library.

Can it be because **some servers block themselves from being "crawled"** by this type of script? Or, maybe I just missed something here?

Thanks beforehand.

Similar questions:

- [PHP CURL & HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4372710/583539)
- [CURL Issue. PHP script not running on call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7721015/583539)

Comment: Did you get any error messages or unexpected output?

Comment: @Jack Maney: Nope, my script / page just keeps "trying" (the browser looks busy loading something) until timed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there's nothing wrong with the above script. And yes, `$target_url = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/press-release/index.html";` returned the intended value (as questioned by @ajreal in his answer).

The problem was actually due to how the IP (of the target page) was being resolved, which makes the answer to this question not related to PHP nor Apache: when I ran the script on the server under test, the returned IP address wasn't accessible. Please refer to this [more detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8578281/583539) / discussion.

One take away: please first try `curl -v` from the command line, which might give you useful clues.

Answer (score 2):

> $target_url = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/press-release/index.html";

I not sure the above expression is actually return the correct URL for you,
this might the cause of all problem.

> Can it be because some servers block themselves from being "crawled" by this type of script?

Yes, it could be.
But I don't have the answer, because you did not put in the implementation details.
This is your site, you should able to check.

In a general, I would say this is a bad idea,
if you are trying to access another page from the same domain,
you can just simply do `file_get_contents(PATH_TO_FILE.'/press-release/index.html');`
(judge by the extension HTML, I assume that is static page)

If that page is require some PHP processing,
well, you just need to prepare all the necessary variables ... then require the file.

Comment: Thanks for the input (+1)! The page that I was trying to include can be static and dynamic. The latter actually is a page "hosted" on a WordPress blog (same server, though) e.g. `http://<my-domain>/blog/category/`. So, I need a way to trigger that page as if it was viewed by a browser; hence, the `cURL` library.

Comment: What options do we have to check whether the site is in fact "crawl-able"?

Comment: There is no option for you to check until you really curl the page. However, you can set a timeout http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Running `curl http://<my-domain>/press-release/index.html` from the command line works. So, it's confirmed that the page indeed can be curl-ed.

Comment: Yes, unless with some weird configuration

Answer (score 0):

Try using HTTP_HOST instead of SERVER_NAME. They're not quite the same.